# How do I know if the programs used in PlayOnLinux can be safely installed?

Tags: security, playonlinux

I'm seeing this large list of mostly commercial programs there and I'm wondering where they came from, if I run the risk of compromising my system by installing any of them.

Answer (score 0):

No you are not. They are all run in a different wineprefix (Minimal Windows system) and if anything goes wrong only the wineprefix will be changed. You can just remove and reinstall the wineprefix.